# Pure virtual interface implemention in the cpp file

Tags: c++, header-files, virtual-inheritance

Is it good practice to put the implementation of a pure virtual interface in a cpp and skip the header file completely?

```
A.h
struct A
{
    virtual void func() = 0;
};
B.cpp
class B : public A
{
   virtual void func() override {
   ...
   }
}
```

Comment: If `B` itself doesn't need to be accessible outside the translation unit, then I don't see why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody must *use* the class `B`, and they have to get instances of `B` from somewhere even if they only ever address them via an `A*`. So you could have for example:

A.h

```
struct A
{
    virtual void func() = 0;
    virtual ~A() {}
};
```

B.h

```
#include "A.h"
A *Bfactory();
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
struct B : public A { ... };
A *Bfactory() { return new B(); }
```

On the other hand, that's quite a "weak" factory function because it only ever returns instances of `B`. Perhaps there will be another factory function somewhere that creates different derived classes of `A` according to its parameters. That function would need to include `A.h`, `B.h`, `C.h` etc, but if it always uses `Bfactory` to create the instances of `B` then it doesn't need the class definition of `B`. So in that case it's fine for the class definition to only exist in `B.cpp`.

Btw, I've returned a raw pointer from the factory. In real life you might prefer to return a `unique_ptr` or other smart pointer. If you do so, then it is in fact possible to avoid the need for a virtual destructor in `A`. But I doubt that it's very often worth it.

Comment: but cant you but a static function inside struct A, something like, static A* create_b();
static A* create_c();
and then in the B.cpp you do A* A::create_b() { return new B; }

Comment: @hidayat: you can. I don't usually design base classes that are supposed to "know about" all their derived classes, but it works. Likewise, in my code you could move the declaration of the free function `Bfactory` from `B.h` to `A.h`. You will anger and upset a few people if you declare a function in `A.h` and define it in `B.cpp` (especially if it's a member function of the class `A`). But they'll survive.